# Prevent "Publish JUnit test result report" changes build result

Tags: jenkins, junit

Currently the build step `Publish JUnit test result report` changes build result to UNSTABLE.

`Build step 'Publish JUnit test result report' changed build result to UNSTABLE`

But I don't want it makes any change to my build status. I try to set

- Health report amplification factor = 0.0
- Allow empty results. Do not fail the build on empty test results (`checked`)

But the plugin still changes the build status. How can I disable updating build results by the plugin?

Answer (score 2):

You can add the parameter:

```
skipMarkingBuildUnstable:true
```

in your jenkins pipeline.
For me it works fine after this:

```
junit testResults: 'target/surefire-reports/junitreports/TEST-RunCucumberTest.xml', skipPublishingChecks: true, skipMarkingBuildUnstable:true
```

This info is not actually visible in plugin website:
https://plugins.jenkins.io/junit/

But this change is merged and available:
https://github.com/jenkinsci/junit-plugin/pull/282